# svg change polygon color onclick

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I have a SVG map of france in my webpage and every district is a polygon, I need that when I click a district the color change and stay that way until I click it again

this is my code

```
function init(evt) {
  if ( window.svgDocument == null ) {
      svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;
   }

function update(district){
    $(this).find("path, polygon, circle").attr("fill", "#0d0");<- what is wrong
   }
```

this is one of my polygons

```
<path id="14" d="M82.387,173.009L109.168,141h2.42l3.33-5.965l20.425,8.818l5.296,0.475l-
 1.876,31.861l5.236,7.5v8.018 l-15.6-1.701l
 0.273-3.599C128.127,186.407,99.635,180.95,82.387,173.009z" fill="#CCCCCC"
onclick="update('14')">
```

as you can see Im getting the onclick event the problem is I cant get the polygon to change color.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please create a JSFiddle?

Comment: I don't know how to create a JSFiddle of a SVG file, I know the problem is simple, just how to change the color of the polygon path

Comment: Could you check what your this contains? Its possible that this already contains the path tag. Hence if you do a find on the path tag, it'll look for path's children and will find nothing

Comment: And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B2MUS/2/) is a sample SVG JSFiddle which you can use to create your fiddle too. Fiddles are always helpful

Comment: This is my model, http://jsfiddle.net/487Pu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check what this holds. A console.log(this) will make your life so much more easier
2. I'll answer 1. This will point to the window object when a function is called. So doing a $(this).attr will find the attributes in the window object and not in the object that you expect.
3. Since you're passing the object id in the function, you can use that to find the element in your document. You can do something like:

   ```
   $('#'+ubicacion).attr("fill","blue")
   ```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/487Pu/1/).